# Vertical align text with icon with shaded box and corner on top only

Tags: html, css

I've a button already created and this is how HTML appear as below:

```
<div class="blue_text"><button class="blue_small" id="blue_small"></button> View this video instead.</div>
```

**CSS as below.** The text to align vertically without changing the existing markup:

```
#blue_text{ color:#48c4d2; font-size:15px; font-family:opensansitalic;}
```

Used this to vertical align the button without changing the existing mark up.

```
​button {
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The button CSS in total:

```
.blue_small {
 height: 40px;
width: 40px;
margin-left:16px;
margin-bottom:1px;
background-color:#fff;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #fff;
background:url(../images/index_video_small2.svg) no-repeat 5px 7px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(64,80,85,0.8);  
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(64,80,85,0.8);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(64,80,85,0.8);
color:#48c4d2; font-size:15px;
    font-family:opensansitalic;}
```

I'd like to combine all of the above into CSS as below with cyan colour shading box? I've never tried this.

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/shade2.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/shade2.png)

UPDATE: I have this < div >< /div > at the bottom of another container but there is gap visible  and tried to close the gap without success? I'm using a current < div >< /div > as below.

```
<div class="blue_text"><button class="blue_small" id="blue_small"></button> View this video instead.</div>
```

This is a gap visible as below:

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/shade4.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/shade4.png)

I'm hoping to use this **< div class="blue_text" > View this video instead.< /div >** to close the gap as below with margin '0'.

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/shade3.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/shade3.png)

UPDATE FRIDAY 2pm: Thank you it worked a treat. It went to a bottom of a browser window. I'm hoping that the blue box to close in between DIV tags for example with this DIV tag as below. This **div class="toogle_wrap"** is one DIV container where I've highlighted a gap to close as below. There will be at least five **div class="toogle_wrap"**, this is one **div class="toogle_wrap"** below so the gap need to close on each of them.

```
      <div class="toogle_wrap">
    <div class="trigger"><a href="#"><span class="trig">1.</span> Deaf person's attention</a></div>
    <div class="toggle_container"> 
    <ul class="lists">
    <li>Learn <span class="bold">how to get</span> a Deaf person's attention.</li>
    <li>Take a step-by-step process.</li>
    <li>Approaching a Deaf and your approach may suggest your intention to communicate.</li>
    <li>You can also <span class="bold">wave</span> to get eye contact or <span class="bold">tap</span> the person gently on the shoulder.</li>
    <!--<li><span class="bold">Watch a video instead:</span> <span class="typicons">Z</span>  <span class="typicn"<h5>Z</h5></span> </li>-->
    </ul>
    <div class="blue_text"><button class="blue_small" id="blue_small"></button> Available in video.</div>
            <<<<<<<<<< The gap is here to close here >>>>>>>>.
            <<<<<<<<<< The gap is here to close here >>>>>>>>.
            <<<<<<<<<< The gap is here to close here >>>>>>>>.
            <<<<<<<<<< The gap is here to close here >>>>>>>>.
            <<<<<<<<<< The gap is here to close here >>>>>>>>.
    </div>
  </div>
```

UPDATE Friday 10pm. Here is the example of DIV. Which DIV is **position: relative** should go in?

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/div.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/div.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my WORKING example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2x6ub/3/

```
div.toggle_container { 
   position: relative;  // this makes the blue_text div being able to align to bottom
   border: 1px solid #000; height: 300px; // this is just to test, remove or adjust
}

.blue_text{ 
    background:#48c4d2; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-size:20px; 
    font-family:opensansitalic; 
    width:400px; 
    font-style:italic; 
    padding:20px; 
    border-top-left-radius:20px;
    border-top-right-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:20px;

    /* to align to bottom of parent container */
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0px;

 }
```

Comment: @Irishgirl Also note your css posted above was wrong #blue_text is an ID you are using class="blue_text" so my css I used .blue_text

Comment: Can you fix this if you don't mind, because my icon is not showing as it should?

Comment: @Irishgirl I don't have the file (../images/index_video_small2.svg) so you need to put your own path here. Can't do magic!

Comment: UPDATE: Is it possible to have this < div >< /div > at the bottom at zero margin without any gap. I've tried it but without success?

Comment: I've update my request to close the gap inside the div. Maybe I didn't make myself clear. What you did worked too, it went to the bottom of a browser window. Instead, I've one DIV tag example above to show you where the gap is supposed to close.

Comment: Just add position: relative to the parent div!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Which parent div is it?

Comment: Do you mean the closest DIV is in CSS? I'm lost, I've tried every DIV. Can you illustrate it in the code example please?

Comment: @Irishgirl Sorry I went away. See my edit. When aligning to bottom of a container you should use position: absolute to the blue_text container and position: relative to the parent (toggle_container) div. Also see my jsfiddle updated and working. http://jsfiddle.net/2x6ub/3/